# Should I include classes in my C++/CLI library via #using "MyClass.obj" and go header-less?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, intellisense

I've recently come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944090/33080) which suggests that my C++/CLI library could skip header files for .NET class declarations, and just use `#using "MyClass.obj"` to reference them. This looked promising.

Having tried it, I'm no longer sure about adopting this approach project-wide. First of all, the VS2015 template for a C++/CLI library declares a .NET class in the header file, and defines the methods in the .cpp file. Had this been an officially endorsed way to program in C++/CLI, surely the template would be header-less.

The other issue has been poor IntelliSense support. The code compiles, but IntelliSense doesn't like it. I've seen two major issues in the first half hour of trying it. In my actual library, internal members are not visible to IntelliSense. In a test project I created, IntelliSense is just flat out unable to even figure out the `#using "MyClass.obj"` directive, telling me "cannot open metadata file" and not recognizing any of the declarations supposed to come from that. To reiterate, the code compiles and works.

**Question**: would you use the `#using "MyClass.obj"` style in VS2015, and does IntelliSense work correctly for you? Is Microsoft committed to making this style a reality or is it somewhat of a failed experiment?

Comment: I don't see a lot of testimonials ahead, #using is rather flawed.  I guess they tried too hard to make it work like #import.  But allowing it on an .obj file certainly bakes the cake, I suppose it was too hard to disallow it :)  Especially with IntelliSense the inherent chicken-and-egg problem is rather severe.  You like to use it *before* you compile.  And like it to be up-to-date without having to recompile.  And worse, you cannot control the build order of the .cpp files in the project unless you doctor a custom makefile.  Use it only on assemblies, the documented usage in the language spec

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I've already run into the build order issue since posting this - not impossible to work around, but another flaw for sure.